# retrieving data from the real-time Firebase database for my activity representing a RecyclerView using an event listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app Kotlin for chat, I have a small problem when I use addValueEventListener()to fetch data from users in my activity for a chat  i retrieve all data in my consol firebase  and my activity for chat it represents correctly profile of the user but when I siginup and reach profile user in RecyclerView  i retrieve all user the problem when I click  logout from menu all is ok but I receive this message "Error to get from database to MainActivity" from  this fun override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)

```
private fun updateUserListFromDatabase() {
    mDbRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear()

            val previousSize = userList.size

            for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val currentUser = postSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                if (mAuth.currentUser?.uid != currentUser?.uid) {
                    userList.add(currentUser!!)
                }
            }

            val currentSize = userList.size
            if (previousSize < currentSize) {
                userAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(previousSize, currentSize - previousSize)
            } else if (previousSize > currentSize) {
                userAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(currentSize, previousSize - currentSize)
            } else {
                userAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, currentSize)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "Error to get from database to MainActivity",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    })
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.logout) {
        mAuth.signOut()
        val intent=Intent(this@MainActivity,LogIn ::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)

        return true
    }

    return true
}
```

I tried to logout from this activity where RecycleView for profile user without receiving this message from override `fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)`:

> Error to get from database to MainActivity

Comment: If you try to use `Toast.makeText( this@MainActivity, "${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` what is the message?

Comment: thinks for response i receive this message "client does not have permission ........"

Comment: Have you set the proper security rules?

Comment: yes :{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Comment: So are you authenticated when you're trying to write data inside the `user` node?

Comment: i thing that i have a listener to  Firebase databases  Realtime and this listener requires that the user is authenticated. When you sign the user out, the listener becomes invalid, and gets cancelled by Firebase with the error"client-does-not-have-permission-to-perform-this-operation",i tray to resolve by removed this listenner in logout by this code "

Comment: i tray in "override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean"logout  i put : if (databaseListener != null) {
                mDbRef.child("user").removeEventListener(databaseListener)
            } but it not resolve

Comment: i tray in rules :{
    //        "rules": {
    //            ".read": true,
    //            ".write": true
    //        }
    //    } it is ok but not secure

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code:

```
Toast.makeText( this@MainActivity, "${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Produces this error:

> Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Because you're using the following rules:

```
{
   "rules":{
      ".read":"auth != null",
      ".write":"auth != null"
   }
}
```

When trying to read data under the `user` node while the user is not authenticated, the above error will always be thrown. So before trying to read something from the Realtime Database, always make sure that the user is authenticated by checking the FirebaseUser object against nullity:

```
mAuth.currentUser?.let {
    //Read data from the Realtime Database.
}
```

So remember, the above rules won't reject the read operation if the user is successfully authenticated in Firebase. However, for testing purposes, while developing the app, you can use the following rules:

```
{
   "rules":{
      ".read":true,
      ".write":true
   }
}
```

But don't forget to secure the database once your app gets into production.

Comment: thinks i now this solution before look in my comment the proble when i uppload app is not secure

Comment: The last rules are not secure but can be used in development, but not in production. In production, you should implement Firebase Authentication and allow only those who is authenticated to read that node.

Comment: but the error cameback with secure rules

Comment: Yes, when you're using the "secure rules", all operations will be rejected unless your user is authenticated in Firebase.

Comment: but when i use  secure rules i recive this message  what i can doin this case i want stop this message error in  my app when i uppload this app in playstore

Comment: The only option that you is to implement authentication. There is no other in which you can use those secure rules.

Comment: Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?